# Is there an INNER JOIN in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, inner-join, powerquery

I am looking to do an inner join of two different tables in an excel spreadsheet based on matching column values. Here is an example:

**Table A:**

```
TICKER
AAPL
AMZN
FB
MSFT
TWLO
```

**Table B:**

```
TICKER      PRICE
AAPL        100
FB          200
TSLA        300
DIS         400
```

The inner join should return tickers and prices from Table B for which there are tickers in Table A:

```
TICKER    PRICE
AAPL      100
FB        200
```

I have tried `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` but am unable to emulate the `INNER JOIN` function that exists in `SQL`. Hoping the StackOverflow community can provide some help :)

Comment: How did your vlookup and/or match functions look? I don't use formulas often but it seems like match or maybe match and index would be a good fit here

Comment: Look into Power Query, but ultimately if you want database features, use a database.  Excel is powerful in its own right but there are things that a database can do that Excel can't.  This can be done but there are many steps and at least two formulas that will be needed, the first will be an array formula that if the dataset is large will greatly slow down the calc times.

Comment: Something like this `=VLOOKUP(TableA!A:A,TableB!A:A,{1,2},FALSE)` but it returns `#NA`

Comment: @moh-s: in addition to the already excellent answers, take a look at [MSDN Scripting Clinic: Much ADO About Text Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974559(v=msdn.10))

Answer (score 4):

To do this you will want two different Formula:

To get the names you will want:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$5)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$2:$C$5,A:A,0))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

To get the values:

```
=IF(G2<>"",VLOOKUP(G2,C:D,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

---

This can be done with one formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$5)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$2:$C$5,$A:$A,0))),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Put this in G2 and copy over and down.

But this doubles the number of array formula and if the dataset is large will cause significant slow downs in calc times.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out really easy with powerquery where you can inner join both tables using the merge queries function after having both tables in memory.

1. Have both tables set up as Excel tables
2. Select a cell within a table then powerquery tab (2013); Get and Transform Data tab Excel 2016 > From Table (new query)
3. This loads the table and the query editor appears. Go to home tab and select Close and Load To

[image: Close]

4. Select Close and Load connection only

[image: connection only]

Repeat steps 2-4 for the other table so both in memory.

[image: both tables]

5. New query > Combine queries > Merge queries

[image: merge]

6. In the window that pops up select both your tables, ensure you highlight the Ticker column in both tables and set join kind to inner join

[image: inner join]

7. Expand the <> arrows on the Table column and deselect the ticker column (removes duplicate column)

[image: duplicate column]

[image: expanded table]

8. Rename columns if required. Close and load result to sheet

[image: load]

9. View result

[image: result]

Comment: as usual, well covered!

Comment: @OurManinBananas I can't tell you how embarassing it feels though with so many images taking up so much space. <Awkward face emoji>

Comment: this question seems to have got everyon'e competetive juices running, at least 4 good answers!

Comment: It shows just how versatile Excel is when so many different methods can achieve the same goal. A useful resource for future readers.

Comment: @OurManinBananas can't look at it like a competition really, prefer to view it as a collaborative effort :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need SQL - use it! :)

It's example of VBA code which uses SQL to join tables. Here's [sample workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCjmlE5xvKaCQAfQJc) with code. New sheet will be created with result. Assuming that Table A is on Sheet1 and Table B is on Sheet2:

```
Sub JoinTables()

    Dim x%
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim sql$, connString$

    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                 "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sql = "SELECT z.* FROM [Sheet1$] x INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] z ON x.TICKER = z.TICKER;"

    rs.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, connString, 0, 1

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            '// Dump header
            For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, x + 1) = rs(x).Name
            Next
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No records were found.", vbExclamation
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    MsgBox "Well done!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: @moh-s: in addition to this answer, take a look at [MSDN Scripting Clinic: Much ADO About Text Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974559(v=msdn.10))

Answer (score 1):

*Well, this sort of is a Catch 22... Because it can be and can't be done at the same time*

---

What I mean under that, Excel is primarily used for static data.  While the results may change based on formulas and what not, in order to check a value it needs to be specified somewhere.

Inner join is a operation that basically takes two entities and creates a new one out of that, like so:

[image]

This is, as  @ScottCraner correctly pointed out, not what Excel was built to do. So that leaves us with 3 options (or at least I could think of that many).

It's important to point out **we are NOT even capable of doing proper `INNER JOIN()`, but we can at least create an illusion - basically an emulation of what it's supposed to do**

---

1. **The manual way** - *I had an answer written up, but @ScottCraner beat me to it and it's more elegant dare I say, so just refer to his instead*
2. **The [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) way** - whch I'll answer below
3. **Via [powerquery](/questions/tagged/powerquery)** - which I'm not that familiar with myself, so you'll have to do your own research / maybe somebody else will answer it.

---

### The [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) way:

> Let's presume we have the following data:
>
> [image]

If we were to describe how `INNER JOIN()` works in algorithmical fashion, it would look something like this.

1. Take range (array of data) `a`
2. Take range (array of data) `b`
3. Compare the data against each other and return a new resulting array `r = a ∩ b`

   3.1 Expression `a ∩ b` can be written "programatically" as the following:

   - `For` every element in `a`:
   - `if` it `exists` in `b`
   - `push` it to the `r`esulting array
   - otherwise go to the `Next` element
4. Return `r`esulting array

Now, for simplicity reason (and for practical usage), I'm not going to be returning an array. What I'm going to do isntead, is to print out every element in column `F` if it matches the criteria (basically do steps `1.` to `3.`)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub INNER_JOIN(ByVal range1 as Range, ByVal range2 as Range)

    Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Your Sheet Name")
    Dim lr as Long 'last active row
    Dim element as Range
    Dim joincheck as Range

    ' it doesn't matter if we loop through range1 and search in range2 or vice versa.
    ' because the element needs to be in both. However for practical reasons, since it's
    ' a lot easier to use Offset() to refer to price of the element, 
    ' we'll loop through range2 and search in range1
    For Each element in range2' loop through all range1 cells
        Set joincheck = range1.Find(element, lookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not joincheck is Nothing Then ' if found in range1
          lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row ' get lr
          ws.Range("F" & lr + 1) = element ' product name
          ws.Range("G" & lr + 1) = element.Offset(0, 1) ' price
        End If
        ' otherwise Find will return Nothing if not found and we can carry on
    Next element
End Sub
```

This should upon invokation emulate the expected result of an `INNER JOIN()` operation.